# Firebase Cloud Messaging for web does not receive messages

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am learning to use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). Before I can implement it into our main project I have to successfully build a simple example in which FCM works. The main project is a web application running on Apache + PHP on the server-side and Javascript on the client-side.

I built the example mostly following the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?authuser=0) step-by-step. I think I do not have 100% understanding about how to integrate all the information into a working code. I have done things in [Set up a Javascript client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?authuser=0) and [Receive messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive?authuser=0) sections. Then I tried to follow the [instruction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message?authuser=0) to send a test notification message, however nothing happened.

The example code I have are of 2 files, the contents are:

[index.php]

```
    <body>
    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-messaging.js";
        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use            
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AI......hidden......po",
            authDomain: "fcm-notification-dxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
            projectId: "fcm-notification-dxxxx",
            storageBucket: "fcm-notification-dxxxx.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "6......hidden......8",
            appId: "1:6......hidden......8:web:0......hidden......9"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        // Initialize Firebase Cloud Messaging and get a reference to the service
        const messaging = getMessaging(app);
                    
        Notification
        .requestPermission()
        .then((permission) => {
            if(permission === 'granted') {
                console.log('Notification permission granted.');
                getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: "BP......hidden......a8" })
                .then((currentToken) => {
                    if (currentToken) {
                        console.log("Got current token.");
                        console.log(currentToken);
                        // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
                        // ...
                    } else {
                        // Show permission request UI
                        console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                        // ...
                    }                       
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                    // ...
                });         
            }
        });
                            
        onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
            console.log('Message received. ', payload);
            new Notification(payload.notification.title, payload.notification);
            // ...
        }); 
    </script>   
</body>
```

[firebase-messaging-sw.js]

This is in the root directory of localhsot, and is an empty script.

From the devtool of Chrome we can as least see that the token was retrieved successfully.
[image]

However, sending test message to the token does not show anything in the client side. I expected that when a message arrives at the client side, the "onMessage" handler will print the payload in the devtool console, but it didn't.

Could you please help correct this example? Thank you very much!

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @AcidCoder  I gave up fixing the code above one year ago. However roughly 6 months ago, when I was really eager to add such a mechenism to my web project, I started over again and I had a success. I am in the middle of some other project now which is not relevent to FCM, and I find that I cannot tell what was wrong in the posted code now. It will take me some time to recall things about FCM. I think the most important thing to do first is that you get a "https"  environment run your web project with FCM, and do not use localhost to do so. Otherwise you will find it frustrating.